# Join Fact Table to Dimension and create new row for each join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, cross-join

I have the following tables:

- A fact table that contains a reviews that have one or more drivers each review
- A Driver dimension table that assigns a bucket for each driver

I'd like to write a script that joins these tables that has a row for each Bucket per Review ID as you can see in the TransformedTable below

[image: Raw Tables and Desired outcome]

I have tried to used various joins but unable to get the desired outcome. Thanks

Comment: Fix your data model!  You should not be storing multiple values in a column.

Comment: Do show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Your data model is wrong, wrong, wrong.  You should fix it!  Why is it wrong?

- You should not be storing multiple values in a column.
- You should not be storing numbers as strings.
- You should have properly declared foreign key relationships.
- SQL Server (and SQL in general) have lousy string processing capabilities.
- SQL has a great way to store lists of values.  It is called a TABLE!

Sometimes we are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad decisions.  If so, you can do what you want, but the query will not be efficient:

```
select rf.reviewid, d.bucket as driver
from reviewfactable rf cross apply
     string_split(rt.driver, ',') s join
     driverdimenstiontable dd
     on s.value = dd.driver;
```

You can also express this using `like`:

```
select rf.reviewid, d.bucket as driver
from reviewfactable rf join
     driverdimenstiontable dd
     on concat(',', s.value, ',') like concat('%,' dd.driver, ',%');
```